# SVG transform animation not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

I'm trying to animate a SVG text element with CSS transforms.
Everything works like expected in Firefox, but Chrome just shows the text
with the first keyframe rule applied.

I tried it with the `-webkit` prefix, but still no luck.

**SVG**

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
      width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >

    <text class="text-need" fill="#FFFFFF" font-size="136">Need</text>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-need {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     animation: slideRight 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0rem, 9rem);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(25rem, 9rem);
    }
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/MoKev/pen/AFdpt?editors=110)

It's a little weired because animating a `clipPath` works fine in Chrome, but won't work in Firefox.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/MoKev/pen/rJzlp)

Answer (score 0):

can your issue be caused by missing the -webkit-prefix?

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

I don't know why your second example won't work on Firefox, but I guess it is also more a browser compatibility issue...

Comment: The codepen uses prefix-free, so prefixes shouldn't cause an issue.
Also if I apply the same animation on a h1 for example, it works.